# TypeError: addTicket is not a function - UseState in modal to print in another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm having some issues with the useState hook and i can't understand why this doesn't work.

I'm building a simple ticket system, and whenever a user clicks on a button it opens a modal and the user can write things about their issue.

I'm having problems getting this modal data to display on another page, where the user can see all the tickets, like a list.

If i do a console.log i can see the user input, but if a try to print this into the page itself it doesn't work.

Throws an error saying `TypeError: addTicket is not a function`
And lastly i'd like to show the modal info in a format(ID - Title - Status), how can i proceed about the id part, for it to iterate itself every submit event?

Many thanks!

Code on the list page

```
const Home = () => {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const openModal = () => {
        setShowModal(prev => !prev)
    }

    const[tickets, setTickets] = useState([]);

    const addTicket = ( title ) =>{
        setTickets([...tickets, { title }])
    }


    return(
        <>
        <PageContainer>
            <HeaderContainer>
                <img src={ gugale } alt="logo-left"/>
                <img src={ logo } alt="logo-right"/>
            </HeaderContainer>
            <TicketsContainer>
            <CreateTicketModal showModal={ showModal } setShowModal= { setShowModal }/>
            <TicketsTop>
                <p>Seus tickets</p>
                <button onClick={openModal}>Novo ticket</button>
            </TicketsTop>

            <TicketTitles>
                <p>ID</p>
                <p>Título</p>
                <p>Status</p>
            </TicketTitles>
            <TicketsInfo>
                { tickets.map(ticket => {
                    <p> {ticket.name} </p>
                })}
            </TicketsInfo>
            </TicketsContainer>
        </PageContainer>
    <GlobalStyle/> 
    </>
    )
}
```

Code on the modal page

```
const CreateTicketModal = ({showModal, setShowModal, addTicket}) => {

    const [ title, setTitle] = useState("");

    const handleName = (e) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTicket(title);
    }

    return (
    <>
        {showModal ? (
            <Background showModal={showModal}>
                <ModalWrapper>
                    <ModalHeader>
                        <p className="createNew" >Criar Novo Ticket</p>
                        <button className="closebtn" onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)}><FiX className="icon"></FiX></button>
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } >
                        <p className="ticketTitle">Título</p>
                        <input type="text" name="ticketInput" placeholder="Escreva uma breve descrição sobre o problema" required onChange={ handleName } className="titleInput"/>

                        <p className="dscptTitle">Descrição</p>
                        <textarea type="text" name="dscpInput" placeholder="Escreva detalhadamente a sua solicitação..." className="dscpInput"/>

                        <p className="anex">Anexos</p>
                        <p className="anexDscp">Envie-nos arquivos, imagens ou textos que possam contribuir para a verificação da solicitação</p>
                        <Anex>
                            <FiUploadCloud className="anexCloud"></FiUploadCloud>
                            <p>Arraste e solte arquivos aqui ou</p>
                            <button>Selecione aqui</button>
                        </Anex>
                            <button addTicket={ addTicket }className="addTkt">Adicionar ticket</button>
                    </form>
                </ModalWrapper>
               <GlobalStyle/>
            </Background>
            
        ): null}
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where have you passed the `addTicket ` as a props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are missing to pass `addTicket` function as prop to the `CreateTicketModal`
component

```
<CreateTicketModal showModal={showModal} setShowModal= {setShowModal} addTicket={addTicket} />
```

Comment: Hey there Tomeu, thanks for aswering my question! Yes, that seemed to be the cased, and i realized i forgot the return on the end of tickets.map, that was the case for not printing correctly, anyway many thanks for your answer, have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass addTicket to the Modal component as props as `<CreateTicketModal addTicket={addTicket} ... />` to access it in the child component.

Comment: Hey there Srosser2, thanks for aswering my question! Yes, that seemed to be the cased, and i realized i forgot the return on the end of tickets.map like i replied to Tomeu, that was the case for not printing correctly, anyway many thanks for your answer, have a good one.